# LoaderManager within FragmentActivity shares context

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-intent, android-loadermanager

Thread name may seem ambigous so I'll explain:

I have a main activity MainActivity which uses SupportLoaderManager and implements it's callbacks:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, InTimeResultReciever.Receiver, Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
...
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
...
loadermanager = getSupportLoaderManager();

loadermanager.initLoader(0, null, this);
...
locationList.setAdapter(locationGeofenceArrayAdapter);
}

@Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        String[] projection = {GeofenceTTBLTable.COLUMN_ID, GeofenceTTBLTable.COLUMN_NAME, GeofenceTTBLTable.COLUMN_ACTIVE};

        cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this, InTimeContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_GEOFENCES, projection, null, null, null);
        return cursorLoader;
    }

@Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        locationGeofenceArrayAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        locationGeofenceArrayAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResumeFragments() {
        super.onResumeFragments();
        locationGeofenceArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

All good, ListView on this activity is populated as expected.
On a listview's row long click I have listener which which brings up DialogFragment with two options each firing an intent that starts another FragmentActivity:

```
Intent editIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), EditDialog.class);
                        editIntent.setAction("editEntry");
                        editIntent.putExtra("geoId", String.valueOf(rowId));

                        getActivity().startActivity(editIntent);
```

This FragmentActivity should serve as advanced dialog with it's own LoaderManager filling ListView able to remove/add rows into it. It is SuportLoaderManager just like in main activity and it implements the same callbacks.

Still working until now, but when I try to manipulate (update) rows of it's cursor/data set returned from `onLoadFinished` things are getting worse. 
The error looks like this (stack trace abreviated):

```
11-23 16:36:13.977 25945-25945/com.tepo.InTime E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.tepo.InTime/com.tepo.InTime.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteQuery: SELECT _id, Name, Active FROM Location
...
11-23 16:36:13.977 25945-25945/com.tepo.InTime E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteQuery: SELECT _id, Name, Active FROM Location
```

It is the same when I use different loader id's upon loader manager initialization.
Can't simulate right now (don't know why) but it happend to me yesterday, that when I was manipulating list called/started fragmentActivity `onLoadFinished` was called, but the one in MainActivity!!

All this brings me to the conclusion that EditDialog being FragmentActivity is somehow connected with MainActivity's cotnext even through I am starting it as activity with intent.

So my questions are: What exactly is happening? What should I do in order to have two separate loader managers onw in MainActivity and the other in FragmentActivity dialog?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to use a `CursorLoader` together with a locationGeofence-`ArrayAdapter` instead of a -`CursorAdapter`  ?

Comment: @k3b, my CursorLoader is for getting data from Sqlite dbs. Not from arrays. Read documentation please.

Comment: i aksed because of `locationGeofenceArrayAdapter.swapCursor(data);` where data is a Cursor. I would have expected `locationGeofenceCursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);` Without the source code of locationGeofenceArrayAdapter we cannot tell you why the cursor ist closed as the exception says

Comment: sorry, I see confusion - locationGeofenceArrayAdapter is cursorArapter, the name is just historical. Nevertheless you see how its used. That adapter only overrides bindView and handles visibility of some UI elements by .setVisibility() that's all. My true point in this is that as I am trying to explain in first post, FragmentActivity is somehow bound with MainActivity (as you can see from error at stacktrace) because when I tamper data in FragmentActivity, MainActivity's loaderManager callbacks are called! --which ends up with exception